# Did Turing ever mention Protagoras regarding the Imitation Game?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, artificial-intelligence, turing

Based on the period when Turing went to school, it is fairly inconceivable he was not well familiar with Protagoras, and the statement that:

> "Man is the measure of all things"

*[I asked a question about this on philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41237/is-protagoras-the-philosophical-root-of-the-turing-test/41277#41277), and garnered answers casting doubt on the ancient axiom's relevance to computing, but any such categorizations, as my own, are purely subjective, and one critique in general regards the "Imitation Game" as not a philosophical subject, where it is more properly a philosophical "rabbit hole".

Regardless, my question here is more direct:

- **Did Turing, or those commenting on the Imitation Game, mention the famous axiom attributed to Protagoras?**

Comment: Where is the link between the ancient [Sophist](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sophists/#Pro) Protagoras with his [statement](http://www.iep.utm.edu/protagor/#SH3b) regarding the "unavoidable" human point of view and AI ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA   It's one of the roots of western philosophy, which leads to [dualism](https://books.google.com/books?id=UG9CtFD56VEC&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=dualism+protagoras&source=bl&ots=HIeoSSGXYd&sig=Ghhqd0K7f3B3rys87Ihvmy9ZgCM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrkMeB-6LVAhVGVj4KHfwaA9oQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=dualism%20protagoras&f=false). It expresses the "universal" truth of subjectivity, as related to man in particular.  Turing's Imitation Game is a recognition of this principle, which is doubly subjective in that the threshold for passing such a test varies with different humans.